# How to show logdata data without any redaction or restriction, for dubugging in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, logcat

I am trying to get the json data, convert it into kotlin object using retrofit,  as per the requirement it needs filter, but didn't get the required respond from logcat to get to know about my filtering, here the screenshot
[image]

I am excepting to get all the data logcat without any * sign in them

Comment: Would you like to share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for the comment I get the urls value by using ->  new JSONObject(map);  that convert my object into json